# Download and then run a file with a script

Tags: linux, script, bash-scripting

I am trying to download 2 files and then run them both. I would like to do this in a script but I am not quite sure how to best accomplish that.

right now I am doing it manually in terminal:

wget http://abc/123/amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./abc/123/amd64.deb

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new file with .sh extension (shell script).
The first line of the script should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

After which you can include your commands line by line.

To make a file executable, you must set the eXecutable bit for a shell script:

```
chmod a+rx script-name.sh
```

Run the script with the command: `bash ./script-name.sh`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a shell script that loops over your input parameters (some urls for wget) you could do it like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
  wget -O ./tmpfile ${!i}
  apt install ./tmpfile
  rm ./tmpfile
  # add more commands here
done
```

Note: With the -O option you can define a filename and then use that file for whatever you need.

Run your script (let's say we called it get-n-run.sh) like this:

```
sudo ./get-n-run.sh http://abc/123/amd64.deb http://abc/123/amd64_2.deb
```

Not sure this is what you actually wanted but I hope it gives you some ideas.

NOTE: Beware of simply executing files with sudo without prior validation. It may contain nice surprises like `rm -rf /`.